# "could not find function" error though function is in the package

Tags: r

In R, I'm getting an error "could not find function...". The function is present inside the package. Still when I run the package, getting the error.

I am getting this error in the `ChainLadder` package while running `MackChainLadderFunctions.R`. For example, the function `checktriangle` is present inside the package in `Chainladder.R`. Still, R is not able to recognize the function or call the function.

Comment: have you loaded the package first? `require('ChainLadder')`

Answer (score 4):

Two problems here.

- function names are case-sensitive (`checkTriangle`, not `checktriangle`)
- `checkTriangle` is not exported from the package (i.e., it's a private function intended for use within the package only), so you need `:::` to access it ... try `ChainLadder:::checkTriangle`.

Using private functions is "at your own risk/programmer beware"; private functions are undocumented, may change in future versions, etc.. If you can find a way to do what you need to do with public functions, that is generally preferred.

AFAICT you're running into this problem because you're trying to `source()` (or cut-and-paste) package code in your R session. This shouldn't happen if you load the package with `library("ChainLadder")` and use the public functions (if it does, please edit your question to give a little more context about how you're using the package ...)