# R package fails devtools::check, because "could not find function" even though the function is imported in NAMESPACE

Tags: r, dplyr, devtools, roxygen2, magrittr

Trying to build my first `R` package using `roxygen2` and `devtools`. I have added a function that uses `%>%` and `mutate` in the `@examples` section. When I run `check()` it fails, because it cannot find the function `%>%` or `mutate`.

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27947344/r-use-magrittr-pipe-operator-in-self-written-package), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51545119/could-not-find-function-error-though-function-is-in-the-package), and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54275199/r-package-devtoolscheck-could-not-find-function) I have tried the following:

I have `#' importFrom magrittr %>%` and `#' importFrom dplyr mutate` in the function's `.R` file. I also have `magrittr` and `dplyr` under `Imports:` in the `DESCRIPTION` file. After running `document()`, my `NAMESPACE` file contains `importFrom(dplyr,mutate)` and `importFrom(magrittr,"%>%")`.

minimal `R/test.R` file:

```
#' Conditional mutate
#'
#' \code{mutate_cond} mutates the \code{data.frame} only on the rows that
#' satisfy the condition.
#' 
#' @param .data \code{data.frame}
#' @param condition expression with the condition to be evaluated
#' @param ... arguments passed to \code{mutate}
#' @param envir environment inherited from \code{parent.frame()}
#'
#' @return \code{data.frame}
#' @importFrom dplyr mutate
#' @importFrom magrittr %>%
#'
#' @examples
#' data(iris)
#' iris %>%
#'    mutate(aux = 0) %>%
#'    mutate_cond(Petal.Length > 1.3,aux = 3)
#'
#' @export
mutate_cond <- function(.data, condition, ..., envir = parent.frame()) {
  condition <- eval(substitute(condition), .data, envir)
  .data[condition, ] <- .data[condition, ] %>% mutate(...)
  .data
}
```

minimal `DESCRIPTION` file:

```
Package: test
Version: 0.1
Date: 2019-06-07
Title: Functions
Description: Some functions I use.
Author: me
Maintainer: me <myemail@email.com>
Encoding: UTF-8
License: GPL-3
Imports: dplyr, magrittr
```

`NAMESPACE` generated with `document()`:

```
# Generated by roxygen2: do not edit by hand

export(mutate_cond)
importFrom(dplyr,mutate)
importFrom(magrittr,"%>%")
```

I expect this example code to run successfully and pass `check()`. Instead I get this error message:

```
❯ checking examples ... ERROR
  Running examples in ‘test-Ex.R’ failed
  The error most likely occurred in:

  > base::assign(".ptime", proc.time(), pos = "CheckExEnv")
  > ### Name: mutate_cond
  > ### Title: Conditional mutate
  > ### Aliases: mutate_cond
  > 
  > ### ** Examples
  > 
  > data(iris)
  > iris %>%
  +    mutate(aux = 0) %>%
  +    mutate_cond(Petal.Length > 1.3,aux = 3)
  Error in iris %>% mutate(aux = 0) %>% mutate_cond(Petal.Length > 1.3,  : 
    could not find function "%>%"
  Execution halted

1 error ✖ | 0 warnings ✔ | 0 notes ✔
```

Also, if I add `require(dplyr)` and `require(magrittr)` to the `@examples` section the error goes away or if I remove the whole `@examples` section the error goes away.

Why won't this package pass `check()`?

Thank you!

Comment: If `%>%` is imported that means you can use it in the code of your package, but not in the examples. So add `require(magrittr)` in the example.

Comment: Or you can make the `%>%` function available to the users of your package without the need to load the `magrittr` package, by importing it and then exporting it. See [here](https://github.com/rstudio/DT/blob/master/R/package.R) for example.

Comment: I don't seem to have any trouble using functions from the `stats` package in examples without loading `stats`. Is that because it is a default package while `dplyr` and `magrittr` are not? Thanks.

Comment: BTW (and to @StéphaneLaurent), using `require(magrittr)` without checking the return status is meaningless: execution will happily continue if the package is not available, which is almost certainly not what you want in that case. If you are going to load a library in code, either do `if (require(magrittr))...` or `library(magrittr)`, never do `require(...)` by itself. (Good reads: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5595512 and https://yihui.name/en/2014/07/library-vs-require/.)

Comment: Yes, `stats` is a base package. You never need to load it. @r2evans: Agreed.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent:  That's not right.  The only package that is guaranteed to be present is `base`.  Others are loaded by default (e.g. typically `stats`, `graphics`, `grDevices`, `utils`, `datasets`, `methods`), but there are other base packages which are not loaded unless you ask for them, e.g. `compiler`, `grid`, `parallel`, etc.)

Comment: `stats` is nevertheless called a "base" package. It is in `r-base`. But that's not very important ^^

Comment: Ah ok you mean not all base packages are loaded by default. You're right.

Comment: Some "base" packages are always *installed/available* but not always *loaded* in non-interactive R sessions.

Comment: @r2evans: That's not right, either.  "Base" packages are part of R, and are *always* available to be loaded.  They can never be updated without an update of R.  That's what "base" means.  The other possibilities for the priority of a package are "recommended", which means most R distributions include them, but they're not part of R and could be updated when R is not, and "contributed", which means you have to install them, they aren't distributed with R.

Comment: You mis-read my comment, I said "always installed/available". If you write a package that relies on (say) `complete.cases`, then a `Rcmd check` is likely going to complain about a function not defined in the global environment. As an example, `stats` is a "base" package (so installed with R) and is always *available* to be loaded in a session -- in interactive sessions it is loaded *by default* -- but is not automatically loaded all of the time. You are right that they are not to be updated separately, but I think that's ancillary to this discussion.

Answer (score 4):

Running `usethis::use_pipe()` in the console will do the trick as well.

Answer (score 0):

Adding

```
exportPattern("^[[:alpha:]]+")
```

to my NAMESPACE file solved the problem on my side.